# Matrix multiplication with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Assume that I have an affinity matrix A and a diagonal matrix D. How can I compute the Laplacian matrix in Python with nympy?

L = D^(-1/2) A D^(1/2)

Currently, I use L = D**(-1/2) * A * D**(1/2). Is this a right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy allows you to exponentiate a *diagonal* "matrix" with positive elements and a positive exponent directly:

```
m = diag(range(1, 11))
print m**0.5
```

The result is what you expect in this case because NumPy actually applies the exponentiation to each element of the NumPy array individually.

However, it indeed does not allow you to exponentiate any NumPy matrix directly:

```
m = matrix([[1, 1], [1, 2]])
print m**0.5
```

produces the TypeError that you have observed (the exception says that the exponent must be an integer–even for matrices that can be diagonalized with positive coefficients).

So, as long as your matrix D is diagonal and your exponent is positive, you should be able to directly use your formula.

Comment: Thx. D is actually a diagonal matrix. I can do it now.

Comment: diag(range(1, 11))         returns a array not matrix, is the reason.

Comment: Good point. This is what pberkes elaborates on in his answer. I updated this answer so as to make this clear.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that it is recommended to use numpy's `array` instead of `matrix`: see [this paragraph](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935) in the user guide. The confusion in some of the responses is an example of what can go wrong... In particular, D**0.5 and the products are *elementwise* if applied to numpy arrays, which would give you a wrong answer. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import dot, diag
D = diag([1., 2., 3.])
print D**(-0.5)
[[ 1.                 Inf         Inf]
 [        Inf  0.70710678         Inf]
 [        Inf         Inf  0.57735027]]
```

In your case, the matrix is diagonal, and so the square root of the matrix is just another diagonal matrix with the square root of the diagonal elements. Using numpy arrays, the equation becomes

```
D = np.array([1., 2., 3.]) # note that we define D just by its diagonal elements
A = np.cov(np.random.randn(3,100)) # a random symmetric positive definite matrix
L = dot(diag(D**(-0.5)), dot(A, diag(D**0.5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only problem I see is that if you are using Python 2.6.x (without `from __future__ import division`), then 1/2 will be interpreted as 0 because it will be considered integer division. You can get around this by using D**(-.5) * A * D**.5 instead. You can also force float division with 1./2 instead of 1/2.

Other than that, it looks correct to me.

**Edit:**

I was trying to exponentiate a numpy array, not a matrix before, which works with `D**.5`. You can exponentiate a matrix element-wise using numpy.power. So you would just use

```
from numpy import power
power(D, -.5) * A * power(D, .5)
```

Comment: Hi Justin,

Thanks for your reply. However, I receive the following error: "TypeError: exponent must be an integer".

Comment: What version of Numpy are you using? Are these regular matrices or sparse matrices. I don't any problem using regular python matrices and raising them to a power.

Comment: Scratch that. I was being dumb and using np.array not np.matrix.

Comment: Thx. What I need is true matrix operation, not dot product or something like that (array multiplication).

Comment: Isn't it the same for diagonal matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Does numpy have square root function for matrixes? Then you could do sqrt(D) instead of (D**(1/2))

Maybe the formula should realy be written

```
L = (D**(-1/2)) * A * (D**(1/2))
```

Based on previous comment this formula should work in case of D being diagonal matrix (I have not chance to prove it now).